# Invoke Alt+F2 through script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

The Alt+f2 in ubuntu shows up Run Application prompt. I can type any command there and open an application through it. How can i do the same programmatically, i mean that i have a command that should be passed to Alt+F2 programmatically. By program i mean a shell script

Comment: How is running through the "Run Application" prompt any different from just invoking it in a shell script directly?

Comment: for example i like to run the following command sftp://nikhil@<my-ip>. When i do it manually by pressing Alt+F2 and typing the above i get password prompt and then i can connect to the remote host and browse his file system. But when i do the same in terminal it says sftp://nikhil@192.16.110.85: No such file or directory. how can i do it through a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gmrun`, which can be installed from the Ubuntu repos. Just `sudo apt-get install gmrun`. `man gmrun` for more info.

It's not exactly the same as the "run application dialog", but there's no clean way to bring that up from a script that I know of.

Comment: thanks for that, but when i type ssh://nikhil@<my-ip> it says no url handler for ssh. any idea of how to make it work?

Comment: @nikhil How about `ssh nikhil@<my-ip>`? Are you trying to open a URL or run a command? Because the command for opening a URL is `gnome-open`.

Comment: @Rafe: But gnome-open sftp nikhil@<my-ip> says the specified location is not mounted. why is it so? what is the proper format to make it work?

Comment: @nikhil I can't tell you why. If you're having issues with gnome-open, that's probably a separate question.

Comment: i read through the man page of gnome-open. It doesnot give much info.

Comment: @nikhil sorry, but I'm not familiar enough with the program to help. Try #ubuntu on IRC, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

Comment: How about adding an example to your answer.

Comment: something like xdotool key alt+f2;xdotool type "firefox";xdotool key Return. hack it at will